# Why can my offset() not take variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I try to line up columns from each sheet into a summary sheet. The Columns nymber in each sheet can vary and each have to be lined up to each other. I try with the following code:

```
  Sub Create_Summary()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, sumSht As Worksheet
  Dim i As Long
  Dim colCount As Long
  Dim rowCount As Long

  Sheets("Summary").Cells.ClearContents

  Set sumSht = Sheets("Summary")
  sumSht.Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

  For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1

     colCount = sumSht.Columns.Count
     rowCount = Worksheets(i).Rows.Count

     Worksheets(i).Range("A:VV").Copy Destination:=sumSht.Cells(1, 
     colCount).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)

  Next i
  sumSht.Columns(2).Delete

  End Sub
```

This doesn't work properly due to the .Offset(, 1) I guess... I dont understand why I am not allowed to use .Offset(, colCount) because then I think it would look good. For some reason if I use .Offset(, i) (which make no sense to do) it's just OK and it can run. Both is a Long variables, so what make the difference and how can I fix this?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried just `.Offset(0, 1)`?

Comment: yeah, due to the sheets can contain more columns than others the later sheets will overwrite the prior ones. I think this .Offset has to be a bit dynamic.. Lets say there is max of 10 columns in the sheets, and if I try .Offset(0,10) I see all info. But if there is sheets with, say 5, columns there is a space of 5 in the summary sheet.. I just want to line everything up next to each other

Comment: Why do you delete a column: `sumSht.Columns(2).Delete` ?

Comment: And, if the number of columns in the detail sheets can vary, why do you hard-code the range `A:VV` ?

Comment: Thats right, no reason to delete (anymore) lol.. And I know about the hard-code A:VV. But I know my variables wont be longer no matter what. But yes it looks bad.. I am not used to this language, I program others, I just need this to work lol. But thanks for answering!

Comment: What is not working properly?  I don't believe it is the `Offset` method as that looks like it should work, so long as the range argument is not in the last column of the worksheet.

Comment: `colCount` is the total number of columns in your sheet (on my version of Excel, that's 16384). By using the `colCount` variable you would be trying to offset beyond the column limit of your sheet ... and that would throw an error. Perhaps your `colCount` definition is what is at fault here?

Comment: @Ambie I thought that too, but then realised there is an `End(xlToLeft)` being used, so `sumSht.Cells(1, colCount).End(xlToLeft)` should be taking cell XFD1 and (usually) finding the first used cell to the left of it (but will never still be in column XFD).

Comment: (a) What do you mean by "This doesn't work properly"?  Does it crash?  (If so, what error message do you get?)  Does it do something you aren't expecting?  (If so, what?)  (b) Can you please copy/paste your code from your VBE window into the question - the current question shows at least one line which will only work if there was a line continuation character (a `_`) at the end so there is a possibility that the code in the question is not the source of your actual problem - that the problem has been masked by the incorrect transcription of the code.

Comment: @YowE3K, I know what you mean, but I think the OP's asking why he can't put `Offset(, colCount)`.

Comment: @Ambie Yeah, `Offset(, colCount)` wouldn't work with that definition of `colCount` (and wouldn't even make **logical** sense with any version of `colCount` that I can think of - the only offset that makes sense is an offset of one column).  It would be really nice to know whether the OP is getting an error or not - I think we are all looking at the `Offset` and I suspect that isn't the actual issue.  (Statements such as "This doesn't work properly due to the .Offset(, 1) I guess" don't make me very confident in that being the culprit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this dynamic, consider:

- getting the range of the detail you want to move for each sheet and storing this in `detailRowCount` and `detailColCount`
- keeping an track of the used columns in `Summary` worksheet by incrementing the value for the number of columns pasted in per `detailColCount`.

Example code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_Summary()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, sumSht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim detailColCount As Long
    Dim detailRowCount As Long
    Dim summaryColCount As Long

    Sheets("Summary").Cells.ClearContents

    Set sumSht = Sheets("Summary")
    sumSht.Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

    summaryColCount = 1
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
        Set sh = Worksheets(i)
        detailColCount = sh.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
        detailRowCount = sh.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

        sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(detailRowCount, detailColCount)).Copy _
            Destination:=sumSht.Cells(1, summaryColCount)

        summaryColCount = summaryColCount + detailColCount

    Next i

    'sumSht.Columns(2).Delete <-- ?

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I looked at it and I somehow got almost the same problem as with offset. Is there anything wrong with my editor or excel lol? The line with .Cells(1, summaryColCount) doesn't work. If I instead write .Cells(1, 1) it can run. It's like its doesn't take variabels ??

Comment: I figured that if I e.g. use .Cells(1, 10) it wont work.. .Cells(1, 1) works. And .Cells(1, summaryColCount) doesn't. You gave me something to work with but I havn't still fixed it.. But thanks for your clear explanation and logics in this language!

Comment: as my first question about offset. WHY does it not work like you do there ? .Cells(1, summaryColCount) ? I don't believe this is a bug, but WHY does it not work. If I understod this this wouldn't even be a topic. It make no rational and logical sense to me haha

Comment: sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(detailRowCount, detailColCount)).Copy _
            Destination:=sumSht.Cells(1, summaryColCount)       <--- this line doesn't work

Comment: @HansPede It would **really** help us help you if you didn't just say "this doesn't work" and instead tell us what happens.  Does it crash? (If so, what error message do you get?) Does it do something you aren't expecting? (If so, what?)

Comment: @YowE3K Honestly I understand your point. And I still really don't know! Suddenly out of the blue it just worked after I said to my self "this has to work". I don't know whats going on lol. It just asked for debug on that line... Thanks boys for trying to help a retard ! Gl